# I cannot get my Python (Pygame) code to get an image which is in the folder

Tags: python, pygame

I am using pygame and trying to display an image, however it keeps saying the following:

Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError

No file 'images/vita_00.png' found in working directory 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0'. File "C:\Programing\Coding\Python\Python3\Tutorial\Developing a Platformer [Rik Cross]\platformer\platformer.py", line 17, in  player_image = pygame.image.load('images/vita_00.png') FileNotFoundError: No file 'images/vita_00.png' found in working directory 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0'.

The file is in the same folder, I am following a tutorial which the link is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVj8-O4MUlQ&list=PLQaniv5ve2yhfYck8nsgU1bw_8bFDSs3h&index=2

The code I am working with is :

```
import pygame
# constant variables
SCREEN_SIZE = (700, 500)
DARK_GREY = (50, 50, 50)
# init
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_SIZE))
pygame.display.set_caption('My Platformer')
# player
player_image = pygame.image.load('images/vita_00.png')
running = True
while running:
    # game loop
    # input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
    print(event)
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
    # update
    # draw
    screen.fill((DARK_GREY))
    screen.blit(player_image, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
# quit
pygame.quit()
```

I really do not understand what I am doing wrong, yes I am very new to python and coding its self.

I do also keep getting this message when running my program in the terminal: cd :

Cannot find path 'c:\Programing\Coding\Python\Python3\Tutorial\Developing a Platformer [Rik Cross]\platformer' because it does not exist.

At line:1 char:6

- c:; cd 'c:\Programing\Coding\Python\Python3\Tutorial\Developing a Pl ...
- 
- CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (c:\Programing\C...oss]\platformer:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand

Can someone please help me.

Thanks

I have tried the full file directory with no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Python! For your script to work, you should be running it in the same directory where `/images` is. Needless to say, make sure that the name (including the png extension!) match what's in the script.

In addition, it looks like in the tutorial they're using some Linux distribution, which generally knows how to handle folder names with spaces. On Windows, on the other hand, you need to be careful about [escaping](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/localization-guide/en/latest/guide/translation/escaping.html) spaces. Try renaming your directories (particularly `Developing a Platformer [Rik Cross]`) to names without spaces and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks so much, I changed the name of the directory like you said and it worked. From now on I am going to be a lot more careful when naming my folders/files. Again thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to mark this as the solution for this question to be closed!